# Unable to pass char[] as parameter to a function

Tags: c++

I have a function

```
int Customer::myFunction(char * cPhoneNumber)
{
    //Something here
}
```

And i am trying to call this function with a parameter like:

```
char cPhoneNumber[MAX_STRING_LENGTH]; //MAX_STRING_LENGTH = 256
memset(cPhoneNumber, 0, sizeof(cPhoneNumber));  
//Some value assigned
myFunction(cPhoneNumber);
```

But i get this error here:

```
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [256]' to 'char'
```

Why am i unable to pass this, please help.

Comment: Looks like a compilation error.  Are you *sure* this is the actual code that's producing this error?  Just use `int Customer::myFunction(char[MAX_STRING_LENGTH]cPhoneNumber)`.Also, please don't use `memset`, the dinosaurs all died away many years ago :))

Comment: Are you sure you have the asterisk in the declaration of `myFunction`? The error says you don't.

Comment: how about char[] or char* const

Comment: post your function prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that the *declaration* of `Customer::myFunction` is actually:

```
Customer::myFunction(char cPhoneNumber);  // note char, not char*
```

You showed us the definition, but not the declaration.  Either that, or you didn't post your definition correctly.